# Own HttpTraceRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

i created my own HttpTraceRepository, for write and read httpTrace from mongodb on capped collection.

Today, i don't understand why HttpTrace is a final class without public constructor.

In my case, when i read mongodb ( findAll method ) to find the last X hours http trace and show it in spring-boot admin UI, it's impossible to instanciante HttpTrace object.

```
@Component
public class MongoTraceRepository implements HttpTraceRepository {

private static final String ADMIN_TRACE = "admin.trace";
private MongoOperations mongoOps;

@Value("${admin.display.trace.last.x.hours}")
private int displayTraceLastXHours;

@Autowired
public MongoTraceRepository(MongoOperations mongoOps) {
    this.mongoOps = mongoOps;
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoOps.getCollection(ADMIN_TRACE);
    boolean collectionExists = mongoOps.collectionExists(ADMIN_TRACE);
    if (!collectionExists) {
        collection.drop();
        // 100 Mo max, 500 000 documents max, capped !
        mongoOps.createCollection(ADMIN_TRACE, CollectionOptions.empty().size(104857600).maxDocuments(500000).capped());
    }
}

@Override
public List<HttpTrace> findAll() {
    Date yesterday = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(displayTraceLastXHours).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());


    return mongoOps.find(new Query(where("timestamp").gte(yesterday)), HttpTrace.class, ADMIN_TRACE)
            .stream()
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getTimestamp().compareTo(o1.getTimestamp()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
@Async
public void add(HttpTrace traceInfo) {
    mongoOps.save(traceInfo, ADMIN_TRACE);
}
```

}

This is the error log :

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: No property request found on entity class org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.http.HttpTrace$Request to bind constructor parameter to!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:273)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1387)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1334)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1276)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:273)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:253)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:198)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:86)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2785)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2448)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2244)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2227)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:770)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a constructor especially suited to create HTTPTrace from a persistence store.

It was added **since 2.1.0** though.